# PHP preg_match with ï

Tags: php, preg-match

How can I use preg_match to accept all normal characters and only the i accented character (ï)?

```
preg_match('#^[ a-zA-Z0-9\[\]()-.!?~*]+$#', $string);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are matching unicode you need to [set the /u (unicode) flag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) then include the unicode character in your range.

```
 preg_match('#^[ \x{00EF} a-z A-Z 0-9 \[\]()-.!?~*]+$#u', $string);
```

There is a full list of unicode characters [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)

Comment: Now I have this error, because of the /u: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '/'

Answer (score 1):

Simply add it to the end of the existing character class...

```
<?php 

  // without the accented i    
  // returns 0, no match :(
  $string = "abcï";
  echo preg_match('#^[ a-zA-Z0-9\[\]()-.!?~*]+$#', $string);

  // adding the accented i to the end of the character class
  // returns 1, a match!
  $string = "abcï";
  echo preg_match('#^[ a-zA-Z0-9\[\]()-.!?~*ï]+$#', $string);

?>
```

Comment: Maybe your file is saved in a format that can not store utf-8. Make sure your php file is saved with utf-8 encoding. This code works for me, so I assume the problem lies outside of the lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Use unicode properties:

```
preg_match('#^[\pL\pN \[\]().!?~*-]+$#', $string);
```

`\pL`  stands for any letter in any language
`\pN`  stands for any number in any language